# mysql get auction data and bids from 2 tables using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `a` auctions and table `b` bids:

Table `a` (Auctions):

```
id status
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
```

Table `b` (Bids):

```
id  auction_id   amount    date
1       1          0.1   2018-01-24
2       1          0.1   2018-01-24
3       4          0.2   2018-01-26
4       4          0.1   2018-01-26
5       4          0.3   2018-01-28
6       1          0.1   2018-01-29
```

What I want to get is the amount of bids, the total sum of bids, the last bid date per auction from table `b` in addition to their id and status from table `a` everything ordered by status:

Something like this:

```
id  status  bid_sum  bid_count  last_bid_date
4     1       0.6       3         2018-01-28
1     1       0.3       3         2018-01-29
3     0        0        0         0000-00-00
2     0        0        0         0000-00-00
```

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.status, SUM( b.amount ) as bids_sum, COUNT( b.id ) as bids_count, MAX( b.dt ) as last_bid_date 
FROM a, b 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY a.status DESC, a.id DESC
```

The problem is that it is returning only auctions that have at least 1 bid

```
id  status  bid_sum  bid_count  last_bid_date
4     1       0.6       3         2018-01-28
1     1       0.3       3         2018-01-29
```

And I need all auctions. Can you please help? Thank you!

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.status, 
    COALESCE(SUM(b.amount), 0) as bids_sum, 
    COUNT(b.id) as bids_count, 
    COALESCE(MAX(b.dt), '0000-00-00') as last_bid_date 
FROM a left outer join b 
  on a.id = b.auction_id 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY a.status DESC, a.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a `left join`:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.status,
       SUM(b.amount) AS bids_sum,
       COUNT(b.id) AS bids_count,
       MAX(b.dt) AS last_bid_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.auction_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.status DESC,
         a.id DESC
```